# what is the best practice for synchronous long-running Process?

Tags: asp.net

I am working on a monitoring project that it monitor different targets including (Switch,Router,PC ,…) in their specific interval(mostly 60 seconds) via SNMP . depending on the number of elements that is going to be monitored, some of the monitoring processes take long time maybe more than 30 seconds .the problem appear when the number of targets are more than 2000 and majority of the monitoring  operations take long time .in this occasion monitoring operations overlap.it is because apparently there is no available thread to allocate them while the cpu has four cores.i tried below options.

I found that there is gap between when monitor come into queue and when it really start to perform.in fact ,  (  startMonitoringOperation – startMonitoring ) = big interval
This big interavel could be more than 2 minute.
I want to know  what is the best practice for synchronous long-running Process .How I can decrease the gap I have mentioned before.

```
     for (int I = 0 ;MonitorsQueue.Count;i++) 
    {
     Var startMonitoring = DateTime.Now;
   1.Threadpool.QueueUserWorkItem(new System.Threading.WaitCallback(DoMonitor),monitorObject);
   2.var task = new task(() => DoMonitor(monitorObject),TakeCreationOptions.LongRuning);
   3. var task = new task(() => DoMonitor(monitorObject));
}
Private void DoMonitor() //this Method take long in some occasions 
{
     Var startMonitoringOperation = DateTime.Now;
     //Monintoring Operation
}
```

Comment: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheMagicOfUsingAsynchronousMethodsInASPNET45PlusAnImportantGotcha.aspx In no case you should do sync operations that take time. Switch to async and you get all kinds of benefits.

Comment: Since these are long running tasks, I'm going to direct you to a different [Hanselman blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx), which discusses how to run background processes in ASP.NET. These long processes should be scheduled, then you can poll the server (or use SignalR, or check on them later) to view the status. That keeps individual requests from taking too long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That seems to be a pool size problem. Increase the the number of threads in ThreadPool class to say 3000 to avoid this. However , I suggest you to use async/await feature of c# language instead of using threadpool to run such threads, as they are not CPU intensive threads and they are just waiting for I/O to accomplish their job.

Through using async/await, no thread would exist during the wait time which is what you can take benefit from.

Good luck,
Ahmad